# Are ‘Haggers Commagers’ and ‘Jessica Christ’ camp High Church Anglican slang/cant?

Tags: slang, religion

In an episode of *QI* (series G, episode ‘[Girls and Boys](https://www.comedy.co.uk/tv/qi/episodes/7/7/)’), Stephen Fry says that there is a camp High Church (Anglican) cant/language game (like Pig Latin), where Holy Communion becomes ‘Haggers Commagers’ and ‘Jesus Christ’ becomes ‘Jessica Christ’.

> - “There is also a very camp High Church nonsense language, in which "Holy Communion" is called "Haggers commagers" and "Jessica Christ" for "Jesus Christ".”

However, in searching, I have found no evidence as to this existing.  Is there such a slang in the Church of England, and if so, were the examples Fry gave correct?

Comment: Slang can be very localised (and short-lived). Do you want to know if it's possible it existed somewhere or whether it is/was a documented 'feature' of the Anglican high church?

Comment: QI is a game show. The format focuses on the panellists answering questions that are extremely obscure.

Comment: What are slangs? What's "a" slang? Slang is not a count noun. An expression might be considered slang, but it can't be considered "a" slang.

Comment: I don't know of any (direct) connection with the Church of England, but I have heard of this style of word being used by Oxbridge students in the late 19th/early 20th century (that's where _soccer_ for Association Football came from). I found [this](https://www.oxfordhistory.org.uk/university/slang.html)

Comment: @KateBunting of those, at my school we used *waggers* (but had no particular affiliation with Oxbridge).

Comment: @WeatherVane - It says that some of the terms passed into general use. I didn't know _waggers_ but have heard or read _champers_ and of course _footer, rugger_ and _soccer_.

Comment: A Google Books search indicates it's in Fry's autobiography *Moab is My Washpot* (1997, p. 168). How widespread it was is unclear, but I'd suggest that should be your first port of call. (Sadly only a snippet is available on Google Books.) It may well have been localised slang, though: institutions like families often have unique names for things.

Comment: As a Cantab, Fry may be one of the few people alive who actually used the slang.

Comment: ***Jessica!*** exclamation 
(S.Afr. gay) a euph. for Jesus! excl.

2003 [SA] K. Cage Gayle. (GDoS)

Comment: It may have been common/originated in St Stephen's House (Oxford) which is a High Church theological college in the Church of England usually referred to as **Staggers.** While I have worked with some of its alumni and do know there was an institutional slang, I have no direct knowledge of its terms.

Comment: @Gio Jessica is South African for gay? I can't even understand the post.

Comment: @Lambie - see https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/b5owvfy

Answer (score 2):

### Haggers Commagers

This looks like slang where the end of the word is replaced by "aggers". Some more insight is given in Fry's [Moab is My Washpot](https://books.google.com/books?id=40mNDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=%22haggers%22%20slang&source=bl&ots=r37X1iDHDo&sig=ACfU3U1cY9g2DBUmjRAryaldOrJf8CzV9A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjekoiYvKj5AhVHE1kFHToyB5AQ6AF6BAgwEAI#v=onepage&q=%22haggers%22%20slang&f=false):

> "Wagger," or "wagger-pagger-bagger," which was used to denote "waste-paper basket," is an example of that strange argot prevalent in the 1920s and 1930s that caused the Prince of Wales to be known as the Pragger-Wagger.
> Even today, in the giddy world of High Anglicanism in such temples of bells, smells and cotters as St. Mary's, Bourne Street, SW3, I have heard with my own two ears Holy Communion referred to by pert, campy priests as "haggers-commaggers" and my mother still describes the agony and torture of anything from toothache to an annoying traffic jam as "aggers and torters."

Oxonist mentions an [-aggers](https://oxonist.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/aggers-suffix/) suffix which is used in *Quagger, Jaggers, Staggers* and also in a slightly different form in *Ugger, Wugger*. [Prince Michael](https://books.google.com/books?id=149YEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT158&lpg=PT158&dq=Coronaggers&source=bl&ots=RYKsecHvVA&sig=ACfU3U0ch2ld-0RBvYweUzKjgyU0x3Psxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVtsuexaj5AhWWGVkFHU7jANUQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=Coronaggers&f=false) (even if he's not the Pragger Wagger) attests "the Coronaggers".

Really, it's almost like some sort of [pragger jogger](https://www.oxfordhistory.org.uk/university/slang.html#:%7E:text=Pragger%20jogger,Practical%20joke).

Cross referencing everything, many of these words appear on Wikipedia's page for [Oxford "-er"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_%22-er%22), which means that's it's probably Oxford slang that spread. (Of the all the words, *soccer* and *preggers* are well known outside England.)

### Jessica Christ

I have not found anything on this but the fact that Fry encountered the other terms through his day to day life means that I'm inclined to believe he's right.

The [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/b5owvfy) entry found by Gio gives solid evidence that "Jessica" is used to mean "Jesus" somewhere (apparently in the South African gay community) but I can't see how this would be related to any British or especially High Church usage.